# Project Euler c++ # 3

Tags: c++

The Question:

"The prime factors of 13195 are 5, 7, 13 and 29.

What is the largest prime factor of the number 600851475143 ?"

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<math.h>
void main()
{
clrscr();
long double x=600851475143,n;
for(n=2;;n++)
    {redo:if(fmod(x,n) == 0)
                { x=x/n;
                  goto redo;
                }
if(x == 1)
    {
    cout<<n
    break;
        }
}
getch();
}
```

I tried solving it without using brute force however my output is always 688543.
I wasn't able to find the glitch.
Please help.
Thank you.

Comment: That `for - goto/label` usage made me cry

Comment: Your indentation is.... creative.... to say the least. Plus non-existent headers, wrong return type for `main`, `goto` controlling `for` flow, `getch()`.... I could go on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your code, translated into *actual* C++ (I have not altered its semantics):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

int main()
{
    long double x = 600851475143;
    long double n = 2;

    while (x > 1) {
        if (fmod(x,n) == 0)
            x /= n;
        else
            n++;
    }

    std::cout << n << '\n';
}
```

[The result is: `6857`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4cd87e292805582d)

**Your algorithm is fine.** Either your compiler is *very* broken, you're working on a 16-bit system, or you made some other mistake that you did not show us.